# JavaFX for Presentation Layer in Standalone Desktop App

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, desktop-application

We are going to create a java standalone Desktop application. We are searching for the best solution for the presentation layer. I saw javaFX and really liked it, but I am a bit confused. Can it be used in standalone Desktop applications?

Can I use javaFX in my standalone Desktop app and also use css to style the Ui?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to use JavaFX in a standalone Desktop app and apply CSS styling to it.

In JavaFX's lingo, this is know as a ["Standalone" or "Self-Contained" deployment](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_overview.htm#CEGHEAHD).

You can even integrate it with [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm) or [SWT](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swt_interoperability/jfxpub-swt_interoperability.htm), if the need arises. Note, though, that it's not possible the other way round.