# Standalone JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to create a standalone, executable JAR that uses `JavaFX` for it's `GUI`?

I want to create an application and send it to a friend that has only the `JRE 6` installed.

Please note, that the solution has to be compatible with either Maven or Gradle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838884/is-javafx-a-choice-for-dynamic-gui-for-desktop-or-standalone-applications

Comment: [JavaFX for Presentation Layer in Standalone Desktop App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360274/javafx-for-presentation-layer-in-standalone-desktop-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX has support for creating standalone native packages.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGIBBCI

Comment: See http://java.dzone.com/articles/create-javafx-executables or http://myjavafx.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/building-signing-and-deploying-your.html for using maven.

Comment: More recent documentation - its 2021 now :)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGIBBCI